# Регулярное выражение для замены идентификаторов вне строковых констант

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно в файле с расширением .java поменять все "_" на "". Буду юзать replaceAll.
Но в случае `String s_s = "ssss_ssss_ssss";` должно стать `String ss = "ssss_ssss_ssss";`

Нашел вот это: `".*_.*"`

Что может быть лучше чем поговорить с собой ;)
Ищем в тексте ".*_.*"

Comment: ИМХО, это невозможно сделать с помощью регулярок.

Comment: Тогда готов выслушать конструктивные предложения )
Например первым заходом пройтись и собрать все в кучу все места где встречается "текст_текст" и куда то их сохранить.
Вторым заходом поменять все оставшиеся _, а потом вернуть на места все что собрали в первом заходе ))) Щас башка уже лопнет )

Comment: Нужно собирать не "текст_текст" а вообще все строковые литералы. (Например `s="\"quoted\"_text"`). А это уже лексический анализ.

Comment: Конечно все зависит от содержимого файла, но, если известно точно, что содержимое подобно `String s_s = "ssss_ssss_ssss";`, то брать отдельно каждую строку и заменять только в первом случае, `replaceFirst`

Comment: А комментарии? Кончено, можно придумать такое выражение как `("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*")|_`, проверять содержимое 1-й группы/подмаски, а потом уж решать, удалять ли символ подчеркивания, но тогда уже не с помощью replaceAll, a appendReplacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение, если вам нужно сохранить подчеркивание внутри кавычек и удалить его в противном случае. Рассчитывая на то, что в каждой строке все кавычки закрыты.

```
_(?=([^"]*[^\\])("([^"\\]|\\.)*"[^"]*)*$)
```

Чтобы записать это в виде строковой константы нужно заэкранировать бэкслеши и кавычки:

```
"_(?=([^\"]*[^\\\\])(\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"[^\"]*)*$)"
```

Comment: Мужик ты гений !!!